# Why was Tokyo sometimes called "Tokio"?

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

The city Tokyo was sometimes called Tokio, as can be seen in [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tokio%2Ctokyo&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1860&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ctokio%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BTokio%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTOKIO%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ctokyo%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BTokyo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTOKYO%3B%2Cc0), and as one example, the WWII anti-Japanese movie [Tokio Jokio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokio_Jokio).

Why was Tokyo sometimes called "Tokiyo"?

The Japanese hiragana for Tokyo is とうきょう, and according to Wikipedia's article on the romanisation of Japanese, the "きょ" component [would be romanised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese#Differences_among_romanizations), under all of the Hepburn, Nihon-shiki, and Kunrei-shiki systems as "kyo".

The section on [historical romanisations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Japanese#Historical_romanizations) has "kio" as a romanisation of "きょ", but that was a romanisation suggested in the 1600s. Were those romanisation schemes still in use in the 19th century, for a city renamed in 1868?

Comment: I don't know, but I'm guessing because English orthography doesn't have a perfect representation for the phoneme "*kyo*" (which *isn't quite* `k`<hard-stop>`yo` and yet *isn't quite* `kee-oh`).

Comment: I have always wondered who was in charge of the Bureau of Transliteration. Somebody with a sense of humor, surely.

Comment: Not a big deal Andrew but did you mean Tokio (as in your film example) or Tokiyo?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Japanese pronunciation, not English as such

Comment: Wikipedia: Tokyo (東京 Tōkyō?, "Eastern Capital") (Japanese: [toːkʲoː] ( listen), English /ˈtoʊki.oʊ/)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo ?listen-link http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cf/Ja-Tokyo.ogg

Comment: @JoeBlow Well spotted, fixed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Actually, the question is about *English* pronunciation of a much-used-in-English Japanese city name.

Comment: @Robusto: But your answer seems to suggest it's an attempt to orthographically represent how *Japanese* speakers pronounce it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Where do you get that? My answer concludes that the transliteration "seems to represent rather an obdurate insistence that the pronunciation be entirely Anglicized for English consumption."

Comment: The question is about the English pronunciation of an extremely common city name.

Comment: @Chenmunka it's asking why a word used in English is spelt the way it is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The name Tokyo is represented by two characters in Japanese: 東京 and the syllables (some fussy linguists insist those be called *morae*) used to sound those out are four: とうきょう or *to-u-k[yo]-u*. Japanese is an isochronous language, meaning every syllable has to be expressed as a (roughly equivalent) duration in time; whatever you call that duration, *Tokyo* has four beats in Japanese but three in English.

Note that the third syllable, which normally represents the sound *ki*, has a tiny subscript *yo* next to it. This is how the Japanese introduce what is essentially a y-glide between the consonant and vowel sounds of certain syllables, because no single character in the syllabary can be used to express those sounds without creating another syllable.

I just asked my wife's aunt, who is Japanese and taught Japanese to college students, about the oddball spelling you point out. She explains that some renderings of Tokyo were given as Tokiyo as a way of bringing the ょ across in the transliteration. This is non-standard, however, and should be avoided, since most English readers hardly care about the phonological representation of such an abstruse issue as this.

*Additional note*: The *u* sounds in the original Japanese, coming at the end of rounded vowels, are almost completely disregarded by Western ears. Syllable duration isn't encoded for meaning to our ears, so those *u* sounds get dropped when a Westerner makes a transliteration. What remains from Tokyo, then, is *to-ki-yo*, which is how it's pronounced in English. The "tokiyo" spelling, then, seems to represent rather an obdurate insistence that the pronunciation be entirely Anglicized for English consumption.

*Further elucidation*: I believe the way to think about Japanese "syllables" is to liken them to music on a phonograph that may be sped up or slowed down. The speed of the passing notes may change, but their relationship to each other at any given speed remains the same. You may hear a Japanese speaker rush through part of a sentence but the syllables will all be there relative to each other at any given speed.

Comment: Wow.  "Japanese is an isochronous language, meaning every syllable has to be expressed as a duration in time":  TBC do you mean **THE SAME** duration in time (in the example, all four would/must be identical); or do you mean each one must have an extent in time?  Thx

Comment: @JoeBlow I think it means the syllables have each a specific defined duration unique to each syllable. tsu or shi are barely said, relative to mo or to.

Comment: Fascinating and thanks.  That must make songwriting very, very, very difficult.

Comment: @JoeBlow: Yes, I mean the same duration. The duration is usually approximate (i.e., not exactly metronomic), but expressed nonetheless.

Comment: @SrJoven: Yes, except it must be noted that even though those syllables tend to be "swallowed" they're each accorded an approximate "beat" duration.

Comment: @JoeBlow: The "same duration" stricture doesn't apply in modern popular music. Also, the Japanese may extend certain syllables (in certain instances) for emphasis, the same way we do. This is especially true for interjections like *ee* or *ma*. For example, it's common to hear Japanese pronounce まさか (*masaka*, an expression roughly equivalent to "what the hell!") as *masakaaaaaaaaa*, extending the final syllable to show extreme consternation.

Comment: I mistakenly spelt it "Tokiyo" in the title, even though I meant "Tokio". Sorry about that.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Still, the "Tokiyo" spelling was definitely used, especially early on during the Meiji restoration (when Japan became opened to the West), though it fell away over time.

Comment: equal time: so in fact, with "tokyo" specifically: are you saying that Japanese people say it with **four** sounds, and indeed, (generally) make all four exactly the same length?  is that right???  (thanks)

Comment: @JoeBlow: Four sounds *more or less* the same length. I doubt if it's exact, but close enough for our purposes. If you are not practiced in Japanese, however, you might not even discern a difference. It might seem to you that the syllables were being emphasized somehow, but you might not recognize the isochronous parceling out into beats; still, they would be present.

Comment: It's also worth noting that even dropped syllables are held for the full beat. E.g., 分かった　(*wakatta*) would be pronounced wa-ka-'-ta, where the ' indicates an absent syllable whose duration is still honored.

Comment: Amazing. who knew?

Comment: I'm not saying each syllable isn't allowed a length, but I do know that if I tried to say do-i-ta-shi-ma-shi-te versus doughytashmashtay, (roughly), I'm thinking I'm going to stand out as an American vs native speaker.

Comment: @SrJoven: A more "Japanesey" pronunciation of どういたしまして would be *do-u-i-ta-sh'-ma-sh'-te* (hyphens only to delineate syllables; the *sh'* indicates a *shi* (し) that is not emphasized the way an American, say, might normally say it).

Comment: One subtlety that's easy to overlook here is that not only does Tokyo have more "syllables" in Japanese, they're also split up differently. The Japanese is roughly To-oh-kyo-oh, rather than the Toh-ki-oh common in English.

Comment: I believe that's what I said, @Bradd.

Comment: It's implied, but for folks who don't already know Japanese it's easy to misunderstand the difference between Japanese kyo-o and English ki-yo. Not sure how important that is, just thought you might want to be more explicit in comparing the two.

Comment: I believe I made it explicit throughout, but especially in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

It is spelled as “Tokio” in several European languages (including Dutch, German, and Spanish). How to represent (transliterate) Japanese words in Latin letters (romanise) has only been standardised recently. It is possible that this spelling was once widely interchangeable with “Tokyo”, the now accepted spelling in English (and Portuguese). The Dutch and Portuguese have deep historical ties to Japan which may be the origin of the alternative English spellings.

While it is often pronounced as “To-ki-yo” I’m English, this barely resembles the modern Japanese pronunciation: I would discourage using spellings apart from Tokyo or Tōkyō in English. The characters きょ (with small よ) is read as on sound “kyo” which has a different meaning in Japanese to きよ “kiyo”. Similarly とう (tou) and きょう (kyou) would strictly romanise with “u” as long vowels under the Hepburn system which is why the Japanese pronunciation is marked with macrons (Tōkyō).